# How to float elements in combination with relative and absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

In the following code snippet:

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <h1>Content goes here</h1>
  <img src="img1.jpg" style="float: right; margin-right: 1em;">
</div>
```

the image floats to the right side of the page. Now I want to replace this image with a jQuery slide show which requires multiple images to be wrapped in a span with relative positioning, while the images are absolutely positioned within the span, essentially forming a "stack" of images on top of each other:

```
<div style="width: 600px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <h1>Content goes here</h1>
  <span style="position: relative;">
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  </span>
</div>
```

(The jQuery code will obviously toggle visibility across img1, img2, img3, etc.)

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o0524475/3/).

I need to float the slide show (i.e. the span with the stack of images that it contains) to the right hand side of the parent container div just like the single image in the first snippet. How do I do this? I've been fighting with it for the past three hours and everything I've tried so far has resulted in my layout being borked.

What in the name of all that's unholy am I overlooking?

Comment: Is setting a width on the slider container (`<span>`) allowed? If so [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/o0524475/7/).

Comment: Hungerstar, preferably not, since images will be resized on smaller displays (e.g. smartphones). Fixing the width of the slider container would break this.

Comment: What about media queries? You can use media queries to adjust the size of the slider container for different device sizes (you can also use percentage widths). Once you're on smaller devices like smartphones, it's unlikely that you'll want to continue floating the slider and instead have it take up the whole width (or close to) of the screen/container.

Comment: As further outlined below, what I was trying to do is not possible, i.e. properly floating and aligning a span that has no known dimensions at the time the browser attempts to render it. I've opted for a different approach. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding for your question I have created following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Rukhsana/o0524475/8/
 1. Change first ...margin-right: 6em;
 2. there need to be add close quotes in src, style

```
<img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg style="position: absolute;>
  <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg" style="position: absolute;>
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with this for longer than I should have, I now realize that what I was trying to do is impossible. I'm trying to float a span without borking my layout, however I'm not willing to assign a fixed width and height to it, expecting it to be whatever width and height are required by the images it contains. At the time the client renders the span, this is an unknown, so the browser is unable to render everything properly within the existing layout.

So what I've done instead as a work-around is a bit of a hack. Crude but effective, I'm preloading all images into the cache, displaying only one, and changing the image source to achieve the slideshow function.

HTML:

```
<p>
<img src="images/shop3.jpg" style="float:right;" class="fadeslide" />
<img src="images/shop1.jpg" style="display: none;" /> <!-- preload -->
<img src="images/shop2.jpg" style="display: none;" /> <!-- preload -->
<img src="images/shop4.jpg" style="display: none;" /> <!-- preload -->
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna
aliguam erat volutpat. Ut wisis enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exerci tution ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
ex ea commodo consequat, et cetera...</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  imgR = new Array ("images/shop1.jpg", "images/shop2.jpg",
                    "images/shop3.jpg", "images/shop4.jpg");
  var imgIdx = 0;
  setInterval (function () {
    $('img.fadeslide').fadeTo(500, 0.1, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', imgR[imgIdx]).bind('onreadystatechange load',function() {
          if (this.complete)
            $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
        });
      imgIdx++;
      if (imgIdx > (imgR.length - 1))
        imgIdx = 0;
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

This will allow me to treat the images as per usual, aligning them as per the other images in the layout. Perhaps not the most straightforward way to do this, but it solves the problem.